# Pygame list index out of range when finding random numbers

Tags: python, pygame

In pygame, I am trying to create a simple program that can randomly generate a 2d map for a game I am working on, with different materials having different rarities. However up until I decided to add the rarity part to the program, it worked perfectly.

After I tried to implement this feature, it gave me this error 
:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pygame/2D game.py", line 63, in <module>
    tilemap[rw][cl] = tile
IndexError: list index out of range
```

here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

#List variables/constants
DIRT = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL = 3

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BROWN = (153, 76, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#Useful dimensions
TILESIZE = 40
MAPWIDTH = 30
MAPHEIGHT = 20

#A dictionary linking recources to textures
textures = {
            DIRT : pygame.image.load("dirt.png"),
            GRASS : pygame.image.load("grass.png"),
            WATER : pygame.image.load("water.png"),
            COAL : pygame.image.load("coal.png"),

        }

#A list of resources
resources = [DIRT, GRASS, WATER, COAL]

#Using list comprehension to create a tilemap
tilemap = [ [DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]

#Initialise pygame module
pygame.init()
#Creating a new draw surface
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH * TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT * TILESIZE))
#Naming the window
pygame.display.set_caption("2D game")

#Loop through each row
for rw in range(MAPWIDTH):
    #Loop through each column
    for cl in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, 30)
        #If a 0,the tile = coal
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = COAL
        #If 1 or 2, tile = water
        elif randomNumber == 1 or randomNumber == 2:
            tile = WATER
        #If 3 - 7, tile = grass
        elif randomNumber >= 3 and randomNumber <= 7:
            tile = DIRT
        #if anything else, tile = dirt
        else:
            tile = GRASS
        #Set the position on the tilemap to the randomly chosen tile
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile


#Loop forever
while True:

    #Collects all the user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #if the user wants to quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #Loop through each row
    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        #Loop through each column
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            #Draw an image of resource at the correct position on the tilemap, using the correct texture
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE))


#Update the display
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `rw` and `cl`?

Comment: You have the ranges for `rw` and `cl` reversed.

Comment: Okay, cheers, Ill try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is stored in a way that the first index represents the heiht and the second the width. So instead of `tilemap[x-direction][y-direction]` you have to use `tilemap[y-direction][x-direction]`. So in your case `tilemap[cl][rw] = tile`

This behavior can also been seen with packages like PIL.